# Coldfusion 5x upgrade

Tags: windows, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

My customer has an existing coldfusion server version 5.x running on windows 2003. They would like to upgrade it to windows 2008/12. We are new to coldfusion, hence want to understand if coldfusion 5.x is supported on 2008/12. If not what should be our migration strategy to upgrade to coldfusion 10.x. Stepped or one shot.

Appreciate your time, thanks in advance.

Comment: Test absolutely everything.

Comment: ColdFusion becomes less tolerant of imperfect code as you get into higher versions.  Expect stuff that works now to break.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We will do all the due diligence to see everything works on the upgraded versions and all functionality is regression tested. My question is 1) Is it supported by product to install cold fusion 5x to windows 2008/2012 ? 2) if not what steps to take to upgrade to coldfusion 10x and install it on windows 2008/2012.

Comment: 1: no it is not supported. That version of coldfusion itself is no longer supported. 2: coldfusion is upgraded, not your code. So build your new server with new coldfusion. Then copy your templates over and start testing. Fix issues as they arise. Rinse and repeat. Coldfusion comes with a code analyzer. It's not perfect but will find some things for you. Start with that after you build the new server and copy the templates over.

Comment: You might consider open source ColdFusion alternatives, Railo or Lucee.  I have been using ColdFusion 11 for over a year without many problems.  Is there a reason that you are looking to jump to CF 10 instead of CF 11?

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers.Really appreciate the help. @ScottJibben: Customer had asked for version 10 upgrade, I will mention to him about the availability of the latest version being 11. Thanks a lot.